# Why does removing an element from a list throw ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, exception, iterator

My program throws `ConcurrentModificationException` when I run the following piece of code. Through some research I found that an element in the list cannot be added or removed when in an iterator loop. What do I do now to remove an element in the `List<Bean>`?

```
for (Iterator<Entry<String, List<Bean>>> iterator = dataMap.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Entry<String, List<Bean>> entry = (Entry<String, List<Bean>>)iterator.next();
    List<Bean> dateWiseValues = (List<Bean>) entry.getValue();
    int j = 0;
    for (Bean statBean : dateWiseValues) {
        for (int i = 0; i < commonElements.size(); i++) {
            if(statBean.getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(commonElements.get(i))) {
                //remove the bean
                entry.getValue().remove(j);
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove it later or you can copy your values to a 'mirror' list and iterate the mirror while removing them from the actual list

Comment: this might also be of interest: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: @Subarachnid, thats much better, post it as an answer

Comment: @MrD : I can't remove it later, cuz I only have chance to remove when in that loop as I'm comparing the values in that loop... But I believe cloning the list would be the only solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using the range-based *for* loop over `dateWiseValues`, use an `Iterator` explicitly so that you can instead invoke [`Iterator#remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29):

```
for (final Iterator<? extends Bean> it = dateWiseValues.iterator();
     it.hasNext();) {
  final Bean statBean = it.next();
  for (int i = 0, last = commonElements.size(); i != last; ++i)
    if (statBean.getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(commonElements.get(i)))                
      it.remove();
}
```

In general, it's safe to remove elements from and underlying collection while iterating over it so long as you do so through one of the collection's iterators.

---

Though we can't see the concrete type of `dateWiseValues`, we know it's a subtype of `List`. Two common concrete types implementing `List` are [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). The prose class-level documentation for each of those classes contains the following admonishment:

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the `Iterator`'s own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Note that it's warning that you must use `Iterator#remove()` for mutation during iteration or you'll face a thrown `ConcurrentModificationException` the next time you use that same or any other iterator walking over the same underlying list.

Answer (score 2):

When you use an enhanced `for` loop, it implicitly uses an `Iterator` behind the scenes.  This is the `Iterator` throwing the `ConcurrentModificationException`, not the explicit iterator `iterator` you've defined in the outer `for` loop.  You cannot remove from a list while an `Iterator` is iterating on it, unless you call [`Iterator#remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29), which removes the current list item and avoids the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Your two options:

- Rewrite the enhanced `for` loop to explicitly use a `while` loop and an `Iterator`, then
  call `remove()` when you want to remove an item.
- Create a `List` of items to remove.  When you determine that you want
  to remove that item, `add` it to the items to remove list.  Then,
  *after* you've finished iterating, call [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) on the original list to remove all the items you wish to remove.